Local development server with uvicorn
It's possible to add ASGI support to python manage.py runserver, so the local development server, by installing daphne and adding it to INSTALLED_APPS.
See docs here. This is how the result looks:
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 02, 2024 - 20:50:29
Django version 5.0, using settings 'contractscounsel.settings'
Starting ASGI/Daphne version 4.1.2 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Is it possible to do the same, but with uvicorn instead of daphne?

You don't have to use the runserver command do to local development. It's just a convenience management command.
The following command has the same effect:
python -m uvicorn contractscounsel.asgi:application --reload


It helps me a lot that runserver also serves the static files.

You can also do that with uvicorn by changing application = get_asgi_application() to application = ASGIStaticFilesHandler(get_asgi_application()) in your asgi.py.
